# Logging Request/Response size in access_log of Nginx

Tags: nginx, access-log

I need to log request/response size(body+headers) in the access_log. Any idea how to do it in nginx?
In apache we can do it using %I..%O format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
log_format combined '$request_length $bytes_sent';
```

According to docs `$request_length` includes the length of request headers and `$bytes_sent` is a total bytes sent to the client in response to the mentioned request.